# How to explicitly include resources of aurelia-dialog@2.0.0-rc.3 with SystemJS+TS?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

Considering changes described here [Aurelia Dialog breaking changes](https://aurelia.io/blog/2018/09/06/aurelia-release-notes-early-september-2018/) we are trying to export our established project based on JSPM and TypeScript so it can be started without this error:

```
system.src.js:1612 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.substr is not a function
    at _ (system.src.js:1612)
    at a.<anonymous> (system.src.js:2475)
    at a.normalizeSync (system.src.js:4457)
    at system.src.js:3302
    at eval (aurelia-b769ffb7bc.js:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.ux-dialog (aurelia-b769ffb7bc.js:1)
    at eval (aurelia-b769ffb7bc.js:1)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at a._apply (aurelia-b769ffb7bc.js:1)
_ @ system.src.js:1612
```

This is our current configuration:
packages.json:

```
"jspm": {
    "dependencies": {     
      "aurelia-dialog": "npm:aurelia-dialog@^2.0.0-rc.2",     
    }
  }
```

bundles.js:

```
"dist/aurelia": {
    "includes": [
     ...
       "aurelia-dialog",
     ...
    ],
    "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": true,
        "rev": true
    }
}
```

and in config.js:

```
  "aurelia-fb495f2376.js": [  
    ...  
      "npm:aurelia-dialog@2.0.0-rc.3/aurelia-dialog.js",
     ...
      "npm:aurelia-dialog@2.0.0-rc.3/renderer.js",
     ....     
    ]
```

Just adding `"aurelia-dialog/resources/*.js"` in `bundles.js` did not help so I guess that it should be done in packages.json?

Where and how exactly we should explicitly include needed `resources` build dependency so it can be bundled and exported properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets [] are the solution.

```
"dist/aurelia": {
    "includes": [
     ...
       "aurelia-dialog",
        "[aurelia-dialog/resources/*.js]",  
     ...
    ]
}
```